# Custom Autonumber using a Trigger

Tags: trigger

I have a trigger that I use to generate an autonumber based on the Record Type. It works fine when I create or update my accounts manually (one by one). But, when I use the Data Loader or the Data Import Wizard, the autonumber doesn't work. I end up having all the new accounts with the same number.

This is my trigger:

```
trigger Autonumber on Account (before insert, before update) {

    list<Account> Acc= [SELECT Id,Name,Customer_Number__c FROM Account WHERE Customer_Number__c !=:null order by Customer_Number__c desc limit 1];
    decimal maxlead = Acc[0].Customer_Number__c;    

    for(Account Acci:Trigger.new){
        if(Acci.RecordTypeId =='012a3456789BCde'){
            Acci.Customer_Number__c = Integer.valueOf(maxlead)+1;
        }
    }  
}
```

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting `maxlead` before your loop so it's the same value for all Accounts within the trigger context. For instance, if you use Data Loader to load 50 Accounts, the value for `maxlead` is set to some number and stays the same for all 50 Accounts in your loop, since it's generated at the beginning of the trigger context.

Do you want it to just increment from the first `maxlead` value? Update it to this:

```
trigger AutonumberRecTypeCustomer on Account (before insert, before update) {

    list<Account> Acc= [SELECT Id,Name,Customer_Number__c FROM Account WHERE Customer_Number__c !=:null order by Customer_Number__c desc limit 1];
    decimal maxlead = Acc[0].Customer_Number__c;    

    for(Account Acci:Trigger.new){
        if(Acci.RecordTypeId =='012a3456789BCde'){
            Acci.Customer_Number__c = Integer.valueOf(maxlead)+1;
            maxlead++;
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, It works like a charm. It does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 5):

Does it have to increment by 1? I don't like implementing auto numbers in a trigger because if you have two concurrent transactions creating an account, they might both query for the max number at the same time and you get duplicates. I prefer to use the built in auto-number feature. It skips numbers since it does it across all record types, but you can be confident they won't repeat.

Also, you should never hard code IDs in your code - they change when going from sandbox to production. It is much better to reference RecordType.DeveloperName.

Comment: This is the better solution. OP, if you don't mind skipping numbers, Daniel's recommendation to switch to the out of box auto-number feature is the way to go

Comment: Record locking can solve the concurrency issues, but high traffic objects might cause row lock errors. The trick is to use another custom object as the mutex to avoid duplicate values. In most cases, this works well, though.

Answer (score 2):

If it is critical to avoid duplicates you will also have to work [Locking Statements](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_locking_statements.htm). These allow one transaction to stop another transaction from progressing until the first transaction has released the lock. So if two requests happen at the same time - e.g. 2 users or a user and the data loader - they are made to execute in turn.

Unfortunately it isn't easy logic to get right and the platform's test environment doesn't give you any mechanisms to write effective tests.

Take a look at the various postings on this site on [for-update](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/for-update) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I come across a situation where a Round Robin created for Account Assignment and and if Account Created by converting Lead  or created Manually then no assignment via Round Robin.  Only challenge here was that when someone assigns an account manually it skips the next person in the round-robin queue.

After a lot of research I found the following solution:

1. Create a Custom Obeject. Change the Standard Name field to AutoNumber.
2. Create a Lookup field for Account .
   Write a Trigger which will create Custom object record if Assigne Mannually = True(This checkbox was created to distingwish Accounts created by converting lead and created Manually)
3. Create a number text field in Account , Create a process builder on Custom object to update the text field on create.
4. Create RoundRobin formula field for RoundRobin Id.
   5) Use this field in workflow for Round Robin assignment.